# Can't run minecraft from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, minecraft

So, I'm making an hacked client for Minecraft, and i wanna click run and then it says this : 
I tried many thing but nothing helps ;(
By the way I'm on Windows
.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/6t5j83

> Error: Could not find or load main class Start
>   , Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release

Comment: I don't really remember, some things from net, its problem for me for a while

Answer (score 0):

What youtube tutorial are you blindly copying code from? If it's one of ConnorM's, stop before he ruins programming for you forever.

You need to sort out the classpath problems that come with MCP. However, I would strongly advise you to learn Java first (as all the skids on HF will tell you). If you can't solve this on your own, you really have no business trying to create a client.